# How to duplicate with collection

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have collection of mesh and cutters. (for example file)

[image]

[image]

I want to make another copy (duplicate) of all the mesh and cutter.

I tried to add empty and parent the mesh and cutter. And when duplicate with Shift+D. Mesh duplicate the cutter and mesh mix in empty and getting different result then the original.

[This is how it is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cG2i.jpg)

Any solution or suggestion how can i make a duplicate of entire collection.

**Note : I do not want to apply any modifiers.**

Comment: so if im not wrong you want to take the collection and create an exact same one , thats easy , right click on the collection and choose **Instance to Scene**